# @ElementCollection get collection throw error 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException'

Tags: java, hibernate

I have Entity

```
public class SmsSending implements Serializable {
....

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "sms_msisdns", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sms_sending_id"))
    @Column(name = "msisdns")
    private Set<String> msisdns;
```

In main thread I get `Set<String> msisdns = smsSending.getMsisdns();` and pass to new thread.

```
executor.submit(new Thread(() -> start(msisdns));
```

And sometime I get error in `msisdns`

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue setting EAGER FetchType strategy in this way:

```
public class SmsSending implements Serializable {
....

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "sms_msisdns", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sms_sending_id"))
@Column(name = "msisdns")
private Set<String> msisdns;
```

For further info refer to [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/).

But please note that you could have performance issues as described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

Answer (score -1):

This is a wrong pattern. You want to keep your fetched entities within that thread, otherwise you will get problems as you mentioned. This is because the underlying Hibernate `Session` object is not thread-safe, thus when you create a new thread, there is no session whatsoever.

Pass the id of your root entity to the thread, make a transaction inside the new thread and fetch the data you need.